# Google Spreadsheet: If certain value in column exists + formula

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas

I have a list with expenses — some of them are monthly and some of them are yearly expenses. Next to them, there is a column with data validation (2 values = monthly/yearly).

Below everything, I'd like to display the total expenses on a yearly basis.

So for the whole column, it should be something like:

> If monthly, then tablecell*12, otherwise — just add the values.

How do I achieve that?

EDIT: Here is an [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1plMtcB99p9eaR9qshoMZ9UiTg8CQ7uUeP_VFkQX1uQw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is it possible to preprocess data and to normalize it, making all data either yearly based or monthly based? At least some spreadsheet screenshot can help to understand the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C1:C4="monthly",B1:B4*12,B1:B4)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, it works if I use semicolons instead of commas:

`=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:E33="monthly";C3:C33*12;C1:C33)))`

Comment: Is it possible to add another argument in there?   For eg.  
 `E3:E33="monthly" and D3:D33="business"`

Comment: @mr.moe sure: `=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((E3:E33="monthly") * (D3:D33="business");C3:C33*12;C1:C33)))`

Comment: not sure if I communicated well enough, let me rephrase it: I only want to use the numbers when the label "business" applies and the use the formula `=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:E33="monthly";C3:C33*12;C1:C33)))`

Comment: try: `=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(IF((C1:C5="monthly") * (D1:D5="business"),B1:B5*12,IF(D1:D5="business", B1:B5,))))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzD3K.png

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I suppose...

[image]

somewhere to the right of where you've written yearly/monthly type in:

```
=IF(B:B="monthly",A:A*12,A:A)
```

And then at the bottom type in:

```
=SUM(C:C)
```

Make sure this sum is not in column 'C'

Comment: Basically like this, but without the C column if possible …